# Can I temporarily disable random / srand in c++?

Tags: c++, debugging, random

I have a very large codebase that uses srand and rand that I need to debug. The random executions make debugging difficult, since bugs occur randomly too. Is there any way to temporary make the library execute deterministically so I can debug the code?

Comment: `rand()` is deterministic if you always pass the same values to `srand()`.

Comment: There are other options such as rr record/rr replay

Comment: I recommend that you abstract out the `rand` calls to your own function. Then for testing it can be used to return fixed values that are known to introduce bugs, otherwise call `rand` (or use [the C++ PRNG classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) which are usually much better than `srand`/`rand`).

Comment: @user202729 this tool gets to less publicity! Thanks for mentioning it

Comment: Yes use dependency injection, don't call rand() directly but use an interface to generate random numbers. Exmple here : https://onlinegdb.com/I9XuhtHH0

Comment: @PKramer you forgot to add virtual destructors

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Whooops! Fixed https://www.onlinegdb.com/5SfAu1Wj7

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to disable `srand`. In some implementations you can redefine it to do nothing and it will work, but that's an ORD violation:

```
extern "C" void srand(unsigned) noexcept {
    // Nothing
}

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    printf("%d\n", rand());
}
```

It works in GCC in my testing and prints the same number every time. You probably can use it to debug your code but it's surely not appropriate for production use.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add a file in the include chain, you can put this in that file:

```
#define rand() (4)
```

Not very pretty, but could help.

[reference](https://xkcd.com/221/)